# CSS - Scale element proportionally if window viewport become too small

Tags: css, viewport, scaling

I have an element centered on screen and wish it be fixed size unless it doesn't fit in window, then it should proportionally scale down. Not just width and height but all it's content. So `transform: scale()` inside of `@media screen` looks like good solution but I can't get how to calc it's argument. I tried to divide current viewport height on const value but it didn't work.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  #myform {
    transform: scale(calc(100vh / 300));
  }
}
```

The main thing is to scale it depending on height, but if it is possible to scale smart depending on height and width would be perfect.

Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtcbf6f9/7/)

Comment: scale don't take unit, and this calc will provide a unit

Comment: @TemaniAfif, calc couldn't return fractional number? I wonder how to calc percentage

Comment: It could, for example if your omit the vh unit it will work because the value will be 0.66 ... but with the unit you will have `0.66vh` which not valid

Comment: you can try vmin , which provide the height or width which ever is lesser, also same with vmax which ever is higher

Comment: @Powercoder, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm dealing with this same issue right now.

Comment: @budkin, I did a trick with javascript: [js](https://github.com/PowercoderJr/MultilevelSpeedDial/blob/master/mlsd.js#L611), [css](https://github.com/PowercoderJr/MultilevelSpeedDial/blob/master/style.css#L66)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone still get here, I didn't find solution in css only but did a trick with css+js.

css:

```
:root {
    --trickyScale: 1;
}

#whereverYouNeed{
    transform: scale(var(--trickyScale));
}
```

js:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    let container = document.getElementById("whereverYouNeed");
    const minScale = 0.75;
    const maxScale = 1;
    let scale = Math.min(window.innerWidth / (container.offsetWidth + 8),
            window.innerHeight / (container.offsetHeight + 8));
    scale = Math.min(maxScale, Math.max(minScale, scale))
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--trickyScale", scale);
}
```

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7qjoga3/)